# 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag' Error

Tags: java, struts-1

'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag' 
Error occured when i am running my struts application in MyEclipse IDE with WebLogic 1o.2 webserver.

```
<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1343897268179' for task '0'. Error is: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Aug 2, 2012 2:17:49 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application '_appsdir_RulesApp_dir'.> 
<Aug 2, 2012 2:17:49 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        Truncated.
```

I do not use any JSF library function though I added this jsf-api.jar file in lib folder than this problem is solved but on the browser window application is still not running. It shows like..

**Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found**

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

Comment: Application is not running in weblogic server whereas it's perfectly working with Tomcat server.

Answer (score 3):

Was facing a similar issue, same error and I was also not having any *Faces* related code in my project. Turned out that there is a jar -> **struts-faces.jar**, which if present in your classpath will make weblogic to search for *faces* jars. Just remove the struts-faces.jar from your lib and error should go away.
[more details](https://amitsmittal.blogspot.com/2014/10/lets-face-it.html)

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure to remove only struts-faces.jar . You can do this from Properties -> build path -> libraries and then Edit in Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the JSF libraries in the classpath (either in the server classpath or embedded in the WAR file).

What the actual jar file should be depends on the JSF implementation you're using. [Here](http://findjar.com/class/javax/faces/webapp/UIComponentTag.html) are some possible choices.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that myfaces-api and myfaces-impl jar files are included in the classpath.